# Repairing/Reinstalling Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, boot-repair, reinstall, data-loss

I have a 32-bit ubuntu 18.04.4 installed in my i386 laptop which is acting up. I want to repair/reinstall my OS but I can't find any 32-bit version of Ubuntu on their website. What can I do to repair/reinstall my OS without losing any data. Sadly I have all my files in the same partition.

Thank you!

[My Ubuntu system information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dumWl.png)

Comment: You can start by telling us what problem you want to repair. Maybe you don't need to reinstall.

Comment: When I connect my wifi card/adapter to the slot and turn on the PC it doesn't boot and says "watchdog bug soft lockup CPU stuck for 23s"

Answer (score 0):

There is no 32-bit Ubuntu 18.4.4 ISO available.

But You can download one of the previous versions of Ubuntu and try to upgrade after installing it to the 18.4.4 version.

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/

Ubuntu 17.04 has 32-bit ISO version available:

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/17.04/

WARNING:
Make sure to backup ALL of Your data first!

Comment: On how to upgrade You can see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460306/ubuntu-upgrade-from-17-04-to-18-04) answer.

Comment: Will my date remain intact?

Comment: No, You have to make a backup first!